# Decrypt the REST API Request URI / body at API Gateway to secure the request data

Tags: java, spring-boot, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway, 3scale

My front-end application will call the back-end Spring boot application with the encrypted URI

Encrypted Request URI
http://example.com/jhliufwf76&gjhgf#hlkjsf

I need to decrypt the URI & forward to respective API for processing. Currently I am using 3scale API Gateway but it seems there is no provision for decrypting the URI.

Is it possible with Spring Cloud Gateway? If yes please give the snippet also.

Encrypted Request URI
http://example.com/jhliufwf76&gjhgf#hlkjsf

Request
http://example.com/order/123?name=abcd

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.